# Run Swing app from Tomcat; can't connect to X11 with DISPLAY=:0:0

Tags: swing, tomcat

I have a small Swing monitoring app that I want to run in the Tomcat 6 JVM.  The app is started by dynamically loading the monitoring class from a webservice running under Tomcat.  This works in Windows but on Linux (Ubuntu 10.4) I'm getting some errors.

My first error was that I was getting a HeadlessException.  I'm not explicitly using headless mode and after searching around I changed Tomcat's library path (via -Djava.library.path in catalina.sh) to point to the client lib (ie. .../java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386/client) instead of the server lib.  I also set DISPLAY=:0:0 in catalina.sh.  This got rid of the headless exception but now I get:

```
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0:0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$100(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:52)
sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:155)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:131)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:68)
java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:380)
java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:433)
java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:158)
com.quinsoft.zeidon.objectbrowser.ObjectBrowser.startup(ObjectBrowser.java:60)
```

At this point I'm stuck.  I've tried a bunch of different things (like explicitly setting "headless=false" and using different values for DISPLAY) and nothing changes.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Version info:

- Tomcat 6.0.28
- Java 1.6
- Ubuntu 10.4

Comment: As a follow-up, I was able to get this running thanks to the Tomcat users email list.  For some reason I don't understand (yet) running Tomcat as a service prevents it from connecting to the X server.  If I run Tomcat directly using startup.sh then the Swing app starts without an issue.  I'll update if I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting '-Djava.awt.headless=true' if you have not already tried it.

Comment: I don't think I want headless mode because I want to run a GUI (ie. Spring) app and they won't run in headless mode.

Comment: In that case, make sure you have started up x-server first and then invoke tomcat.

Comment: My x-server is running, so I suspect there's something in the setup of Tomcat that prevents it from finding it.  I assume that for security reasons Tomcat is automatically installed without the ability to run X apps.

Comment: Have you already tried setting DISPLAY to say server_name:0.0 or ip_address:0.0 ? Also make sure that x-server is not blocking any connections.

Comment: Reading up on the net about this issue points back to the same option '-Djava.awt.headless=true'

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I appreciate the help. I've tried different flavors of DISPLAY and none of them work.  99.9% of the hits for headless exception discuss '-Djava.awt.headless=true' because few people are dumb enough to run a GUI app from Tomcat :)

Comment: Ha, ha..all the best. Do let us know the outcome.

Comment: @Kevin Did you find any solution for this? I've got stuck with the same problem.